# How to create JWKS public/private key pair in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cryptography, public-key-encryption

How to create a JWKS public/private key pair, similar to the one that can be created manually at https://mkjwk.org/, that includes the **Key ID** (`kid`) and **Key Use** (`use`)? I used the `cryptography` module for generating a RSA key pair and `python-jose` for extracting the keys as JWK, but the created keys do not include `kid` and `use` (unsurprisingly, as they haven't been specified anywhere).

Code:

```py
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa
​
from jose import jwk, constants
import json
​
key = rsa.generate_private_key(
    public_exponent=65537,
    key_size=2048,
    backend=default_backend()
)
public_key = key.public_key().public_bytes(
    encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
    format=serialization.PublicFormat.SubjectPublicKeyInfo
)
private_key = key.private_bytes(
    encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
    format=serialization.PrivateFormat.TraditionalOpenSSL,
    encryption_algorithm=serialization.NoEncryption()
)
​
print(json.dumps(jwk.RSAKey(algorithm=constants.Algorithms.RS256, key=public_key.decode('utf-8')).to_dict()))
print(json.dumps(jwk.RSAKey(algorithm=constants.Algorithms.RS256, key=private_key.decode('utf-8')).to_dict()))
```

Generated public key by above code snippet (no `kid` or `use` properties):

```
{
    "alg": "RS256",
    "kty": "RSA",
    "n": "tqbcR_6JC....OKQ",
    "e": "AQAB"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `kid` is just a piece of metadata (any string) that is not being used in the process of generating the key.

In case of the `use` it is probably somewhat similar, though depending on the use you want different scheme for asymmetric cryptography (you can refer to the most well-known asymmetric cryptography system of [RSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)) for both encryption and signing schemes' description).

All in all, you can most probably recreate the exact structure of JSON adding appropriate keys to JSON dict based on the information above.

Comment: *you distribute the Private Key* - then it's not private anymore. Signatures are created with the private key and verified with the public key.

Comment: So how would you describe e.g. RSA with reference to names from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem) in application to signatures? Would you use Private Key for the Public Key and vice-versa? How that helps understanding what you mean?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, but the part about signing is also [explained](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Signing_messages) in the Wikipedia Article

Comment: @jps is correct. You sign the data with *your* private key, and everybody else verifies the signature with *your* public key.

Answer (score 10):

Another way to generate JWKS public/private key pair using the `jwcrypto` library:

```py
from jwcrypto import jwk

key = jwk.JWK.generate(kty='RSA', size=2048, alg='RSA-OAEP-256', use='enc', kid='12345')
public_key = key.export_public()
private_key = key.export_private()
```

Generated public key by above snippet:

```
{
    "kty": "RSA",
    "alg": "RSA-OAEP-256",
    "kid": "12345",
    "use": "enc",
    "e": "AQAB",
    "n": "0YclBn...vV7y7w"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the below code in order to generate JWKS including information about the certificate (e.g x5t, x5c).
Since the certificate already contains the information about the public key, you don't need to pass the public key separately.

To understand more on how to generate a digitally signed RSA pair for JWT, refer to [here](https://www.scottbrady91.com/openssl/creating-rsa-keys-using-openssl)

```py
import base64
import json

from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.hashes import SHA1
from jose import constants, jwk
from cryptography import x509
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization


class JWKSGenerator:
    def __init__(
        self,
        *,
        file_path: str,
        kid: str,
        use: str = 'sig',
    ) -> None:
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
            self._cert_pem_raw_data: bytes = f.read().strip()

        self._cert = x509.load_pem_x509_certificate(self._cert_pem_raw_data, default_backend())
        self._kid = kid
        self._use = use

    def _create_x5t(self, ):
        digest = self._cert.fingerprint(algorithm=SHA1())
        return base64.b64encode(digest).decode('utf-8')

    def _create_x5c(self, ):
        cert_val = self._cert.public_bytes(serialization.Encoding.DER)
        return base64.b64encode(cert_val).decode('utf-8')

    def process(self):
        jwks = jwk.RSAKey(algorithm=constants.Algorithms.RS256, key=self._cert_pem_raw_data).to_dict()

        jwks.update({
            "x5t": self._create_x5t(),
            "x5c": [
                self._create_x5c()
            ],
            "kid": self._kid,
            "use": self._use,
        })
        print(json.dumps(jwks, indent=4))
        return jwks


JWKSGenerator(
    file_path='<complete path to certificate pem file>',
    kid="key_id_123",
).process()
```

In case you don't have the certificate, you can use below code:

```py
jwks = jwk.RSAKey(algorithm=constants.Algorithms.RS256, key=open('<path_to_public_key>'>, 'rb')).to_dict()
jwks.update({
    "kid": '<key_id>',
    "use": 'sig',
})
print(json.dumps(jwks, indent=4))
```